# how to concatenate two _T strings?

Tags: visual-c++

How to concatenate these strings?

```
_T("http://www.google.com/") + _T("intl/en/privacy.html")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert one of them to a `CString`, something like: `CString(_T("http://www.google.com/")) + _T("intl/en/privacy.html");`